# I cannot find output files even though the are saved in the container apparently

Tags: python, docker

I can't find output files of arpeggio using Windows Power Shell (the algorithm was created for Linux)

I've tries to add > to create an output text file , but this only creates an output file of this:

```
INFO//08:56:42.365//Program begin.
INFO//08:56:42.402//Loaded PDB structure (BioPython)
INFO//08:56:42.403//Detected that the input structure contains hydrogens. Hydrogen addition will be skipped.
INFO//08:56:42.630//Loaded PDB structure (OpenBabel)
INFO//08:56:42.640//Mapped OB to BioPython atoms and vice-versa.
INFO//08:56:42.780//Typed atoms.
INFO//08:56:42.789//Determined atom explicit and implicit valences, bond orders, atomic numbers, formal charge and number of bound hydrogens.
INFO//08:56:42.826//Initialised SIFts.
WARNING//08:56:42.830//Chain termini could not be determined for chain E. It may not be a polypeptide chain.
INFO//08:56:42.831//Determined polypeptide residues, chain breaks, termini
INFO//08:56:43.009//Percieved and stored rings.
INFO//08:56:43.034//Perceived and stored amide groups.
INFO//08:56:43.039//Added hydrogens to BioPython atoms.
INFO//08:56:43.045//Added VdW radii.
INFO//08:56:43.050//Added covalent radii.
INFO//08:56:43.053//Completed NeighborSearch.
INFO//08:56:43.058//Assigned rings to residues.
INFO//08:56:43.061//Made selection.
INFO//08:56:43.173//Expanded to binding site.
INFO//08:56:43.174//Flagged selection rings.
INFO//08:56:43.175//Completed new NeighbourSearch.
INFO//08:56:43.245//Calculated pairwise contacts.
INFO//08:56:43.386//Program End. Maximum memory usage was 83.82 MB.
```

As you can see, the file is created and saved somewhere but when I ran cat I couldn't find any of the files suggested as output files by the developer.

```
docker run --rm -v C:\directory:/<path to file> -it arpeggio python arpeggio.py /file -s RESNAME:xxx -v
```

After this, I should be able to run `python show_contacts.py file.pdb -s` to show the interactions on PyMOL

```
PS Z:\> docker run arpeggio python show_contacts.py fie.pdb -s
But, this is the outcome
docker : Traceback (most recent call last):
At line:1 char:1
+ docker run arpeggio python show_contacts.py file.pdb -s
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Traceback (most recent call last)::String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

  File "show_contacts.py", line 509, in <module>
    with open(contacts_filename, 'rb') as fo:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/arpeggio/file.contacts'
```

So, no output file was created 
Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by running this code in PowerShell:

```
docker run --rm -v :/<host-directory>:/<container-path> -u uid:gid -it arpeggio python arpeggio.py /container-path/file.pdb -s RESNAME:xxx -v
```

I was able to get my uid and gid after running ubuntu 18.04 and pulling docker ce on Windows as a subsystem and I have to clarify that the same code is useful to use in docker if you add `-H localhost:2375` and select "Expose daemon" after doing a right click on Docker and click on Settings.

Hopefully, this might be useful for anyone having the same issue.